# Parsing SOAP response to JAVA object

Tags: java, xml, soap, unmarshalling

I am trying to parsing a Soap response string to a JAVA object to get those parameters.

Here's the response string:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns0:submitCdus1Response xmlns:ns0="http://example.com/">
<MessageId>D421425215</MessageId>
<NoOfDay>14</NoOfDay>
<Status>Y</Status>
<LastControlPoint>SBC</LastControlPoint>
<LastEntryDate>20210415</LastEntryDate>
<ReplyDateTime>20210427114126848</ReplyDateTime>
<TypeOfTravel>A</TypeOfTravel>
</ns0:submitCdus1Response>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

My Object class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="submitCdus1Response", namespace="http://example.com/" )
public class TravelHistoryResponseDTO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "MessageId")
    private String MessageId;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "NoOfDay")
    private Integer NoOfDay;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Status")
    private String Status; //Y , N ,
    @XmlAttribute(name = "LastControlPoint")
    private String LastControlPoint;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "TypeOfTravel")
    private String TypeOfTravel;// A
    @XmlAttribute(name = "LastEntryDate")
    private Date LastEntryDate;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "ReplyDateTime")
    private Date ReplyDateTime;
      
    public String getMessageId() {
        return MessageId;
    }
    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        MessageId = messageId;
    }
    public Integer getNoOfDay() {
        return NoOfDay;
    }
    public void setNoOfDay(Integer noOfDay) {
        NoOfDay = noOfDay;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }
    public String getLastControlPoint() {
        return LastControlPoint;
    }
    public void setLastControlPoint(String lastControlPoint) {
        LastControlPoint = lastControlPoint;
    }
    public String getTypeOfTravel() {
        return TypeOfTravel;
    }
    public void setTypeOfTravel(String typeOfTravel) {
        TypeOfTravel = typeOfTravel;
    }
    public Date getLastEntryDate() {
        return LastEntryDate;
    }
    public void setLastEntryDate(Date lastEntryDate) {
        LastEntryDate = lastEntryDate;
    }
    public Date getReplyDateTime() {
        return ReplyDateTime;
    }
    public void setReplyDateTime(Date replyDateTime) {
        ReplyDateTime = replyDateTime;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TravelHistoryResponseDTO [MessageId=" + MessageId + ", NoOfDay=" + NoOfDay + ", Status=" + Status
                + ", LastControlPoint=" + LastControlPoint + ", TypeOfTravel=" + TypeOfTravel + ", LastEntryDate="
                + LastEntryDate + ", ReplyDateTime=" + ReplyDateTime + "]";
    }
}
```

My code:

```
    SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null,
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(responseString.getBytes()));
                    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(TravelHistoryResponseDTO.class).createUnmarshaller();
                    TravelHistoryResponseDTO dto = (TravelHistoryResponseDTO)unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());
```

But I am getting
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:[http://example.com/"](http://example.com/%22), local:"submitCdus1Response"). Expected elements are <{}submitCdus1Response>

Anyway to solve this and able to map the parameters to  the java object?

Comment: Are you not missing a space in your XML file : `<S:Envelopexmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">` ? There should be a space separating `Envelope` and `xmlns`. If not, then the file is not valid XML, and there is no real point in trying to parse it using standard tools. (Same for `submitCdus1Responsexmlns`). Once that is corrected, you should probably set the namsepace in the `@XMLRootElement` annotation to `http://example.com/`

Comment: The xml format is my typo, i have edit this post, thanks. I tired to include the namespace to the `@XmlRootElement(name="submitCdus1Response", namespace="http://example.com/" )` but the values are still null for the object.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the JAXB object mapping : you are using `@XmlAttribute` for the various fields of your object, but the XML data you are trying to read are not XML attributes (`<ns0:submitCdus1Response MessageId="xxx">`) but XML elements (`<MessageId>xxx</MessageId>`).

Therefore all you have to is switch from `@XmlAttribute` to `@XmlElement` to match the  mapping object to your actual XML.

As a note : if this comes really out of a SOAP call, chances are that you have a XSD Schema somewhere that defines the XML structure that is used here. JAXB comes with a code generation tool that will create the JAXB Objects (e.g. `TravelHistoryResponseDTO`) for you, deriving the data from the XSD. The tool is called `xjc` (you can google / search for it), it comes with the JDK and or can be found in maven plugins, (and more). This is the kind of mistake the tool would have prevented.